# Anyone know why I can't center my ul with html because of an image

Tags: html

I have been working on this code since yesterday (my first time using html so please excuse my syntax and cascading) and am having trouble getting my ul to center properly with the image being in the header, because it makes the hyperlinks shift. Any insight onto how I can fix this with some simple HTML style/formatting? Also, any tips on the code itself would be greatly appreciated. (Please try to provide some level of explanation so that I can actually learn versus copy and paste). Thanks!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

   <style>
    .listStyle {
      font-size:175%;
      text-align:center;
      list-style-type:none;
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto;
      padding: 0;
    }
    </style>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
   <span><img src="url" alt="YMF Logo" style="float:right;" height="auto";width="100px;margin: 0 auto;"></span>
  </head>
  <body>
    <b>
      <u>
<h1 style="position:relative;top:40px;text-align:center;font-size:175;">
Warehouse Quick Links
</h1>
</u>
<div style="position:relative;top:20px;">
  <ul class="listStyle">
    
  <li>
    <a href="url" target="_blank" rel="noreferer noopener"> Outbound Sheet </a> 
  </li>

  <li>
    <a href = "url" target="_blank" rel="noreferer noopener"> Spoils Form </a>
  </li>
  
  <li>
    <a href = "url" target="_blank" rel="referer noopener"> Check-In Form </a> 
  </li>

  <li>
    <a href = "url" target="_blank" rel="referer noopener"> Amazon Pallet Guide </a>
  </li>

  <li>
    <a href = "url" target="_blank" rel="referer noopener"> Amazon Packaging Guide </a>
  </li>

  <li>
    <a href = "url" target="_blank" rel="referer noopener"> Shipstation </a>
  </li>
    
  <li>
    <a href = "url" target="_blank" rel="referer noopener"> Amazon Seller Central </a>
  </li>

  </ul>
</div>
</b>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You have a `<span>` and `<img` in the `<head>`, which is invalid HTML. Those are only allowed in the `<body>`. And the `style` must be in the `head`, or the `body`.

Comment: I fixes all of this, thank you for the feedback. Any other tips on how to fix the formatting?